# Flattening python object and list of child objects to a single dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a list of asset objects that has a list of attribute objects into an array of dictionaries. I'm trying to denormalise the parent/child relationship into a single dictionary.

For the context of my code below I have an asset object with a short_name and the asset object has a list of attributes with an attribute_value and attribute_name.

My intended result is something like this;

```
[{'name': 'Test', 'attr': 0.9}, {'name': 'Test2', 'attr': 0.5}]
```

So far I've written it like this;

```
a_list = []

for a in self.assets:
   asset_dict = {'name': a.short_name }
   
   for x in a.attributes:
      asset_dict = asset_dict | { x.attribute_name : x.attribute_value }

   a_list.append(asset_dict)
```

This works fine, but I'm looking for a neater solution.

I experimented with;

```
result = [{'name':a.short_name} | {x.attribute_name : x.attribute_value} for x in a.attribute for a in self.assets]
```

However, I just can't seem to get the syntax correct and not sure if it is possible to do something like this.

EDIT: Inputs on request (excluding the class definition);

```
self.assets = [Asset(short_name='Test'),Asset(short_name='Test2')]
self.assets[0].attributes = [Attribute(attribute_name='attr',attribute_value=0.9)]
self.assets[1].attributes = [Attribute(attribute_name='attr',attribute_value=0.5)]
```

Comment: Can you add example inputs to your question so we can understand your problem better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
a_list = [
    {'name': a.short_name} |
    {x.attribute_name: x.attribute_value for x in a.attributes}
    for a in self.assets
]
```

or

```
a_list = [
    {'name': a.short_name, **{x.attribute_name: x.attribute_value
                              for x in a.attributes}}
    for a in self.assets
]
```